# Monoid of bimodules

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional connected algebra over a field and $X$ the set of all $A$-right modules $M$ with $End_A(M) \cong A$.

Say $A$ has property $(*)$ in case the following is true:

Given $M, N \in X$, also $M \otimes_A N$ is in $X$.

In this case $X$ is a monoid.

Are there interesting algebras $A$ with property $(*)$ and can one describe the monoid in this case? When is it a group?